# Why is this regex not matching URLs?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^(?=\w+)(-\w+)(?!\.)
```

Which I'm attempting to match against the following text:

```
www-test1.examples.com
```

The regex should match only the `-test1` part of the string and only if it is before the first `.`and after the start of the expression. `www` can be any string but it should not be matched.

My pattern is not matching the `-test1` part. What am I missing?

Comment: Are those spaces present in your actual regex? Do you know how lookaheads work? Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: Sorry, removed them now. Why the downvote?

Comment: If `www` can be any string, then I'm not sure what the requirement is of the text that should come before the match, but shouldn't be matched itself.

Comment: @SebastianProske I looked up some information about lookaheads. I am using Java (`java.util.regex.Pattern`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is one of the only languages that support non-fixed-length look-behinds (which basically means you can use quantifiers), so you can technically use the following:

`(?<=^\w+)(-\w+)`

This will match for `-test` without capturing the preceding stuff.  However, it's generally not advisable to use non-fixed-length look-behinds, as they are not perfect, nor are they very efficient, nor are they portable across other languages. Having said that.. this is a simple pattern, so if you don't care about portability, sure, go for it.

The better solution though is to group what you want to capture, and reference the captured group (in this case, group 1):

`^\w+(-\w+)`

p.s. - `\w` will not match a dot, so no need to look ahead for it.

p.p.s. - to answer your question about why your original pattern `^(?=\w+)(-\w+)(?!\.)` doesn't match. There are 2 reasons:

1) you start out with a start of string assertion, and then use a lookahead to see if what follows is one or more word chars. But lookaheads are zero-width assertions, meaning no characters are actually consumed in the match, so the pointer doesn't move forward to the next chars after the match. So it sees that "www" matches it, and moves on to the next part of the pattern, but the actual pointer hasn't moved past the start of string. So, it next tries to match your `(-\w+)` part. Well your string doesn't start with "-" so the pattern fails.

2) `(?!\.)` is a negative lookahead. Well your example string shows a dot as the very next thing after your "-test" part. So even if #1 didn't fail it, this would fail it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The first regex that you mentioned in your answer was the one I was looking for. I appreciate the detailed caveats you mentioned. How about a more stricter version of the regex where `-test2` expects itself to be followed by `.`? `(?<=^\w+)(-\w+)(?=\.)`

Comment: @genonymous That's up to you. What I posted will match for e.g. `www-test1-foo.examples.com` which is a valid (sub) domain. But if you want to more strictly expect nothing after `-\w` then sure, add `(?=\.)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is the lookahead. In this case, it's inappropriate if you want to capture what's between the `-` and the first `.`. The pattern you want is something like this:

```
(-\w+)(?=\.)
```

In this case, the contents of capture group 1 will contain the text you want.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KvGyYB/2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not want www and dot (.) to be matched. That's why I used lookaheads. Now that I think more about it, regex in original question should have been like `^(?=\w+)(-\w+)(?<=\.)` with positive look ahead and positive look behind. But this one is also not working.

Comment: @genonymous Lookbehind should be on the left, lookahead should be on the right.

Comment: @genonymous: is there a particular problem with matching the `www` but not capturing it? Because, generally speaking, you can't have an arbitrary-length lookbehind like you seem to want.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Yes, the requirement is to not match www(or basically anything that appears between start of the test expression and first `-`) and first `.` . I can write a very simple regex `-test2` (or `-\w+` if I want to make it general) and it will do what I want. But it will also return many instances of `-test2` that appear anywhere in the test expression. I want to restrict it to the match that happens only between the start of the test expression and first `.`. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @genonymous: Why? That seems... odd, at best. Just don't use the `g` flag, and it'll return only the first match.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz  Yes, I can use first match. But it will also match `test1` in `www.examples-test1.com` and this match is not desired.

Comment: @genonymous: if you're basically not allowed to touch the preceding text, what you're asking is impossible. Why do the requirements specify that you only match the particular text? You can match the preceding text without capturing it, using the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=www)\-\w+(?=\.)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xEpno7/1